# Method addObserver must be called on the main thread

Tags: android

I started getting this illegal state exception recently.

This is the stack trace:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UploaderServiceThread1640451978001
> Process: com.sister.ivana4k, PID: 2032
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
> at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:317)
> at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.(ComponentActivity.java:231)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.(FragmentActivity.java:127)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.(AppCompatActivity.java:87)
> at com.sister.ivana.database.OrmLiteBaseAppCompatActivity.(OrmLiteBaseAppCompatActivity.java:33)
> at com.sister.ivana.database.DBServices.VehicleServices.(VehicleServices.java:28)
> at com.sister.ivana.upload.UploadType.getFileURL(UploadType.java:548)
> at com.sister.ivana.upload.UploadType.createSpinItPicturesUploadDescription(UploadType.java:475)
> at com.sister.ivana.upload.UploadType.getUploadRequest(UploadType.java:299)
> at com.sister.ivana.upload.Uploader.startCompletionRequest(Uploader.java:704)
> at com.sister.ivana.upload.Uploader.processQueue(Uploader.java:443)
> at com.sister.ivana.upload.Uploader.handleMessage(Uploader.java:198)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

I have searched around and found that I could potentially wrap the call to do it on the main thread, unfortunately from what I can see the call is made by an internal library so I am not sure how I could resolve it or at least mitigate it.

What can I do? Let me know if you need more info.

Vehicle Services class:
public class VehicleServices extends OrmLiteBaseAppCompatActivity {

```
    private final String vinNumber;
    private final Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public VehicleServices(String vinNumber, Context context) { //line 28
        this.vinNumber = vinNumber;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        try {
            DatabaseHelper helper = getHelperInternal(this.context);
            final Vehicle vehicle = helper.getVehicleDao().queryForId(this.vinNumber);
            if (vehicle != null) {
                Dao<Project, ?> dao = helper.getProjectDao();
                for (Project project : dao) {
                    final String projectID = project.getProject().replace(",", "");
                    if (projectID.equals(vehicle.getProject())) {
                        return project;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Util.logError("Database error adding new VIN", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have to also mention that I inherited this codebase a few days ago and I am aware that best practices were thrown out when building this. (Memory leaks and bugs everywhere, spaghetti code, you name it) I am looking for a way to fix this particular exception to the greatest degree possible.

I have access to all the files except android internal libraries.

Comment: Can you post the code around the interaction with the ivana library that crashes the app?  Also add this to the line before the call to the line that crashes, `Log.d("thread",Thread.currentThread().getname())`    If its `main` then it might be a problem with the library. If its not `main` then its your problem.

Comment: If you have access to your "internal library", you can directly change the method to be called in main thread.

Comment: From the error message, `com.sister.ivana.database.DBServices.VehicleServices.(VehicleServices.java:28)` is creating a brand new instance of an Activity on a background thread. You can't just create a new instance of an Activity on *any* thread and have that be useful (it needs to be created by the Android framework). Can you include that code?

Comment: I have added more information, thank you

Comment: @barryalan2633 Have you find any fixes?

Comment: @DeepakRattan, unfortunately, soon after posting, I got moved to a different project so I was not able to work on this issue any longer

Comment: @barryalan2633 Thanks for the response mate .I can understand .